# Cloning a React project and can't start it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am a beginner with React and I have trouble cloning a functional React project.

After clone and cd into the folder, try to start with `npm start` but what shows up in my terminal is the next error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path <my_project_path>\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<my_project_path>package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I'm sure it's a novice mistake but when I create a project don't show that error.

Thanks one more time to this community

Comment: It looks like that `package.json` file is missing. Check that

Comment: You have to run your command in `package.json` level.

Comment: before that you have to install the required packages with `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run npm install first.

Comment: As I know... a novice mistake.... thank you! it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

at first, check if you have a package.json in the path then run this code `npm install`
the check-in the package.json have script his name  start 
if it found to run this code  `npm run start`